# Can silver metal be used to electrochemically reduce copper?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, ions, metal

I have a solution of copper(II) ions and several cations.  I am trying to reduce the copper ions to copper metal with electricity.  My Ideas was to use silver as the anode and a copper wire as the cathode.  I have seen people say to do this using platinum as the anode, however this is expensive.  I was wondering if silver could be used as an alternative anode because it has a higher reduction potential than copper.  If not, could any metals besides gold and platinum work.  I have attached a picture of my proposed cell.  I have tried the cell, but the silver began to corrode and form a silvery deposit, probably a silver salt.

[image]

Comment: No as it is less reactive than copper, moreover if you look at these reactions you will see that Ag2SO4+Cu=CuSO4+Ag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, electrically depositing copper(II) ions onto a silver electrode should be possible. As it should also be possible to deposit those ions on just about every other cathode in existence as long as there are no more noble cations in solution.

However, depending on what you want to *do* with the copper, you may run into problems. Do you want copper-plated silver? That should be fine. Do you want to redissolve the copper to get a pure solution by acidifying? In that case, you cannot use the typical $\ce{HNO3}$ method because that would oxidise the silver, too, and you would end up with a mixture of copper(II) and silver(I) nitrates in solution.

Comment: No, I am trying to get the copper as a powder by reducing it with a copper cathode and silver anode.  I started with copper ore, dissolved it in acid, and I am now trying to bring it to the metallic state.  I wanted to make sure that the silver would not oxidize or corrode.

Comment: @popgalop You won’t get copper as a powder, you will get a metallic plating on your cathode.

Comment: Yes, but I have heard that it mostly flakes off.  I was going to have the copper in a plastic tube with only the end exposed and scrape the copper off of the end of the wire.  The idea is to obtain the pure copper from the ore.

Comment: @popgalop Can’t comment on that but my lab course experiment (with platinum cathodes) had a fine sheet of copper on the cathode that you needed to get off with $\ce{HNO3}$.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure the silver wouldn't corrode in the strongly oxidizing conditions.

Comment: @popgalop You have reducing conditions if you want to reduce copper …

Comment: I attached a sketch of my proposed cell.  I plan on reducing the copper ions at a copper cathode, and using the silver metal as an inert anode.

Comment: @popgalop Ah! In that case that should be no problem and oxygen should be generated at the anode given the correct conditions. Sorry for misunderstanding!

Comment: Or maybe $\ce{Ag}$ _would_ dissolve to some extent, and that would be a problem. Normally people use copper anode for this purpose, so as not to bother about impurities. Copper in, copper out.

Comment: Otherwise, use carbon (graphite). It will oxidize, but who cares. It won't reduce anyway.

Comment: I don't want to use carbon, because it will contaminate the product.  And I don't want to use copper because I am trying to quantitatively determine the amount of copper in the solution.

Comment: Then still use carbon. It won't contaminate anything (that is, except atmosphere).

Comment: Carbon will flake off as a powder and contaminate the copper from watching videos

Comment: Then put the carbon electrode in another vessel and join them by a salt bridge.

Comment: I tried the silver, but it began to corrode and flake off into the solution.